# What is the meaning of the term "shape" of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

Often heard this while reading about JS objects but couldn't find any definition or explanation anywhere.

Comment: Probably the specific properties an object has. But it's certainly not an "official" term.

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: It's the fields and their order of an object used as a [record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 2):

At a very high level, an object's shape is the order/structure of keys and values. An example object:

```js
const exampleObj = {name: "Johnny"}
```

The best way I can think to answer this uses Typescript, which allows you to define shapes of objects:

```js
type nameObject = {name: string}
```

this is defining the shape of the nameObject as an object (denoted by the curly braces) with a key of `name` and a value of type `string`. In Typescript, you define a variable's type like this:

```js
type nameObject = {name: string}
const exampleObj: nameObject = {name: "Johnny"}
```

The shape of the object is defined as a single key `name` that must be a string. All objects MUST be "shaped" like this, or they will not be of type `nameObject`. This is what is meant by shape.

Object shape is just the order / sequence of keys and their corresponding values, as a value for a key can be an object itself, with more nested keys/values.

Some more reading:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html
https://dev.to/amitkhonde/javascript-internals-object-shapes-23i3
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#description